# CSS not rendering as expected. Can anyone point out the mistake?

Tags: html, css

I have a code snippet which styles the div boxes. However the css is not rendering as per expected. Can anyone help me point out the mistake. I have created [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sbutmyax/1/) for the same.

#### Below is the CSS code.

```
div.orange {
  width: 1280px;
  height: 320;
  background-color: rgb(255, 102, 0);
}

div.white {
  width: 1280px;
  height: 320;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

div.green {
  width: 1280px;
  height: 320;
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
}
```

#### Below is the HTML code

```
<div class="orange"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the div part of eg. div.orange and putting px after 320?

Comment: I expect three div boxes with the CSS classes applied.

Comment: Need to add px after the value 320 in height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add px to heights :

```
div.orange {
  width: 1280px;
  height: 320px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 102, 0);
}

div.white {
  width: 1280px;
  height: 320px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

div.green {
  width: 1280px;
  height: 320px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The height rule has to have a measurement unit such as **px**:

```
div.orange {
  width: 1280px;
  height: 320px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 102, 0);
}

div.white {
  width: 1280px;
  height: 320px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

div.green {
  width: 1280px;
  height: 320px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
}
```

Comment: that was so stupid of me to forget adding the px. Thanks for pointing it out..it works now.

Answer (score -1):

So, first question: Did you import your CSS File in the HTML file??
If not do it like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css" />
```

Second thing is, you must not write:

```
div.green { your properties }
```

This is the normal way:

```
.green { your properties }
```